# Fourier font and \textregistered symbol

Tags: fonts, symbols

I use TeXLive 2010 on Win XP and I notice that while the `\textregistered` symbol (an R in a circle which is normally placed next to trade names) appears well with the default CM font, it appears incorrectly with the fourier font (which I like much). Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}

Bananamark$^{{\scriptsize\mathrm{\textregistered}}{}}$

\end{document}
```

Any suggestion on how to make the `\textregistered` symbol appear well with the Fourier font?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You shouldn't ignore the log-file. LaTeX tells you

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \textregistered invalid in math mode on input line 10.
```

Use one of these:

```
Bananamark$^{\mbox{\scriptsize\textregistered}}$
Bananamark\textsuperscript{\textregistered}

%needs amsmath
Bananamark$^\text{\textregistered}$
```

Comment: Thanks for showing different ways of implementation. And 1 vote up.

Answer (score 11):

There's no need to use math mode (which results indeed in something wrong):

```
\textsuperscript{\textregistered}
```

Comment: Thanks and 1 vote up. I accept Ulrike's solution as it gives more possibilities.